# Can a liquid exist at absolute zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

I believe a liquid can't exist at absolute zero. This is mainly due to the fact that at absolute zero, matter will take the lowest point of internal energy and this must be a solid. The molecules in a solid are stuck together very tightly in a regular pattern and move very little. Molecules in a liquid have more energy than molecules in a solid.

Hence, solids they have low amounts of internal energy.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no-one else has answered I'll point out that helium is liquid at absolute zero below a pressure of about 25 atmospheres.

Helium remains fluid at absolute zero because the helium atoms sit in a potential that is close to a simple harmonic oscillator and therefore has a zero point energy. This means the expectation value of the kinetic energy is non-zero even at absolute zero and the resulting motion is enough to prevent the crystal lattice from forming.

Helium is unique in having a very low mass, so the zero point oscillations have a large amplitude, and very weak interactions between atoms, so the lattice energy is small. These conspire to keep it liquid at absolute zero. No other element or compound has this combination so all other elements and compounds are solids at absolute zero.